# Beamer color doesn't match

Tags: beamer, color

I am trying to get the color R0, G130, B202 in beamer. It looks like:
[image]

But the following Beamer document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{PMSProcessBlue}{rgb}{0,130,202} 

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=PMSProcessBlue}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=PMSProcessBlue}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=PMSProcessBlue}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{All}{Sub}
words
\end{frame}
                                                                                                     
\end{document}
```

produces a much lighter color:

[image]

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Use `RGB` model instead of `rgb` (see manual of `xcolor` package).

Comment: That is right (and fast). Thank you. It is surprising that `rgb` and `RGB` give different results for a color declaration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `RGB` model (parameters between 0 and 255) instead of `rgb` model (parameters between 0 and 1). See [p.10, `xcolor` manual, v2.11](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/xcolor/xcolor.pdf#page=10).

```
\definecolor{PMSProcessBlue}{RGB}{0,130,202}
```